# Обстоятельство перед словом "это" после именительного темы / подлежащего

Tags: синтаксис, тире, синтаксический-разбор, обстоятельство, именительный-темы

*В современных компаниях довольно большая текучка кадров. Два года — **обычно / сегодня / в данном случае** это приемлемый стаж в корпоративной среде.*

Правильно, что обстоятельство ставится после тире и перед "это"? Конечно, обстоятельство можно перенести в начало предложения, но меня интересует именно такой вариант.

Ещё интересует состав подлежащего и состав сказуемого. "Два года" — подлежащее, "стаж" — сказуемое? Или "два года" — именительный темы, а "это стаж" — подлежащее и сказуемое соответственно?

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте контекст, так как корректность предложения  (обоснованность инверсии слова "это") вызывает сомнения.

Comment: Я бы этот текст записала так: В современных компаниях довольно быстрая текучка кадров, и  два года  сейчас  - это  приемлемый стаж  в корпоративной среде. Как-то не получается у меня составить предложение с количественным сочетанием в качестве именительного темы.

Comment: Во-первых, не "быстрая" текучка, а большая. Во-вторых, почему: "два года - обычно...", а не "Обычно, два года"?

Comment: @Нижегородец *Конечно, обстоятельство можно перенести в начало предложения, но меня интересует именно такой вариант.*

Comment: @Нижегородец По поводу "большой" согласен.

Comment: @Sharon Не могли бы пояснить, почему "сейчас" вы поставили перед тире, а не после?

Comment: Это инверсия.  При нормальном порядке слов: Сейчас два года - это приемлемый стаж в корпоративной среде.  Обстоятельство плохо вписывается в интонационную структуру. Впрочем, не обращайте внимания, я собираюсь удалить комментарий и, возможно, чуть позже дам ответ.

Comment: При такой модификации "это" становится лишним словом. Я не вижу проблем в исходном предложении: ничто не мешает менять "это" и "сейчас" местами.

Comment: Alex_ander, Ваше мнение, безусловно, интересно и будет учтено автором вопроса. Оформите его, пожалуйста, в виде ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*В современных компаниях довольно большая текучка кадров. **Два года — обычно / сегодня / в данном случае это приемлемый стаж в корпоративной среде.***

1) **Правильно ли построено предложение?**

Инверсия слова ***это*** не кажется  обоснованной. Правильно: *Два года — это обычно приемлемый стаж в корпоративной среде.*

То есть правильным является  предложение, в котором тире ставится перед связкой ***это***.

**Примечание.** Фактически предложение со связкой ***это*** можно рассматривать как **частный случай именительного темы**, когда предмет (подлежащее) сначала называется, а затем заменяется **указательным местоимением** в форме И.п. ср.рода, которое считается **связкой** между подлежащим и сказуемым.

2) **Можно ли перестроить предложение под именительный темы?** Например, это может выглядеть так:

В современных компаниях довольно большая текучка кадров. ***Стаж в два года — сегодня он вполне приемлем в корпоративной среде.***

Это изолированный номинатив в препозиции в роли именительного темы.  https://studfiles.net/preview/2682296/

Примеры: Человек, идущий в завтра... Он немыслим без широты взгляда на жизнь (газ.); Но знамя - вот оно, реет на гребне, над самой вершиной (Б. Пол.).

3) **О грамматике**

Номинативные конструкции (номинативные и неполные предложения, изолированный номинатив) **пока не имеют единой теории.** Сейчас изолированный номинатив может рассматриваться **отдельно** от грамматической структуры предложения.

Но вот еще у Розенталя похожие предложения с именительным темы толковались иначе (**как единая конструкция**): Писать посредственные вещи — на это не нужен никакой талант.  Инфинитив в функции именительного темы, **сказуемое выражено целым предложением.** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92

Comment: *Фактически предложение со связкой **это** можно рассматривать как частный случай именительного темы...* Насколько я знаю, функция связки — присоединять сказуемое к подлежащему. В случае именительного темы "это" не может быть связкой, "это" становится подлежащим. Простите, если автор вопроса снова не соглашается с ответом :-)

Comment: У нас есть официальное понятие о связке ЭТО, но формально предложение со связкой напоминает именительный темы. У него та же структура. И если ЭТО поставить в другой падеж, то мы уже получим именительный темы, как у Розенталя. Писать посредственные вещи — это несложное дело (связка). Писать посредственные вещи — на это не нужен никакой талант (именительный темы, Розенталь). Поэтому предложение со связкой можно перефразировать и оформить как именительный темы (такой вариант я привожу в ответе).

Comment: *Писать посредственные вещи — на это не нужен никакой талант*. Но здесь "это" уже является членом предложения — дополнением. Проясню свою позицию: я не спорю о возможности увидеть в нашем предложении именительный темы, я говорю о том, что в случае именительного темы "это" уже является членом предложения — подлежащим, а не связкой.

Comment: Да, разумеется. Перестройка структуры изменяет вид синтаксической конструкции. А Вы-то считаете, что Ваш пример имеет отношение к именительному темы? Перестановка ЭТО выглядит неестественно (связки уже нет, а именительного темы не получилось). Вообще говоря, ИТ - это выигрышная (выразительная и эмоциональная) конструкция, хорошо, если Вы ее освоите.

Comment: Сейчас напишу, как я считаю. Но перед этим хочу кое‑что уточнить. 1) Вы считаете "Два года — обычно это…" инверсией. Получается, "Два года — это обычно…" — нормальный порядок слов. Но где это установлено? Связка обязательно должна быть как можно ближе к тире? И почему при инверсии "связки уже нет"?

Comment: 2) Я правильно понимаю, что интонация именительного темы зависит от используемого знака после него: точка, многоточие, тире, восклицательный знак, вопросительный знак — и не имеет обязательной интонации конца предложения (понижение тона и длинная пауза)? Зная это, я смогу сказать, что здесь ближе.

Comment: 1) Тире разделяет группу подлежащего и сказуемого, связка ставится сразу после тире. Это однозначное требование, об этом говорится у Розенталя. Ваше предложение не подходит под это определение (тире стоит не перед связкой). Можно написать: Два года сегодня - это обычно приемлемый стаж в корпоративной среде. Тогда наречие будет относиться к группе подлежащего. Но смысл будет выражен некорректно.  2) Именительный темы может оформляться отдельно или включаться в структуру предложения, отделяясь от него тире. Интонация соответствующая (Вы прочитайте эту тему по ссылке).

Comment: *Можно написать: Два года сегодня - это обычно приемлемый стаж в корпоративной среде. Тогда наречие будет относиться к группе подлежащего. Но смысл будет выражен некорректно.* Про какое именно наречие вы говорите? «Сегодня» относится к группе подлежащего, «обычно» — к группе сказуемого. Верно? Правда, из этих наречий нужно выбрать одно: я их через косую черту написал в своём вопросе.

Comment: Правила такие. Вы можете включить наречие в группу подлежащего или сказуемого, а между группами поставить тире. Если вы считаете, что это общее наречие, то тире вообще не ставится. Но если наречие входит в группу подлежащего, то оно приобретает определительное значение. То есть мы получаем "сегодняшние два года", а какой в этом смысл?

Comment: Почему "сегодняшние два года"? В комментарии к вопросу вы говорили, что "два года сегодня" — это инверсия и "сегодня" — это также общее наречие.

Comment: Подобным образом в предложении *Два года — это обычно/сегодня приемлемый стаж в корпоративной среде* "обычно/сегодня" также общее наречие. Оно относится не к группе сказуемого, а ко всему высказыванию. Так ведь?

Comment: *Если вы считаете, что это общее наречие, то тире вообще не ставится*. Проблема как раз в том, что тире точно ставится — из-за связки "это". И наш вопрос такой: где будет располагаться общее наречие — слева или справа от тире, если наречие ставить не в начале предложения, а между подлежащим и сказуемым?

Comment: Заключительный диагноз по теме. 1) Предложение с ЭТО в вашем варианте  построено как именительный темы, но оно читается не лучшим образом. Пример: "Главная проблема для малого бизнеса сегОдня - это удушающее влияние местных властей".  Поищите похожие варианты в Нацкорпусе. В структуре предложения всё важно, даже количество слов (для создания равновесных фраз). И логические ударения надо расставить верно.2) В своем ответе я привела пример именительного темы, которое читается нормально (легко, язык "не спотыкается"). 3) Ваша задача - добиться нужного эффекта в рамках выбранной конструкции.

Comment: В вашем предложении не была нарушена грамматика или какое-то правило. Просто не было равновесия фраз: тире (пауза) разделяла два коротких слова и следующую объемную часть. Непонятно было, как расставить тонические ударения,  а они присутствуют в каждом предложении. У меня не получилось читаемое предложение с ЭТО в середине. Поэтому я делаю вывод, что такие конструкции сомнительны. Но это я так думаю, а вы поищите в текстах, чтобы прийти к определенному мнению. Пожалуй, ничего нового я Вам больше сказать не могу.