# Позиция обстоятельства в СИС

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, семантика, наречия, обстоятельство

Данной вопрос появился из [этого](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/449034/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE/450008?noredirect=1#comment461011_450008).

1. **Обычно** желание — это лишь часть решения о покупке.
2. Желание — это **обычно** лишь часть решения о покупке.

Меняется ли смысл от изменения положения обстоятельства в указанных предложениях? Является ли обстоятельство в примере 2 также детерминантом, то есть относится ли оно ко всему предложению и характеризует ли ситуацию в целом, или оно относится лишь к сказуемому? Может ли детерминант стоять в середине предложения?

Answer (score 1):

1) **Детерминант** — это обстоятельство иди дополнение, которое распространяет не отдельные члены предложения, а предложение в целом, то есть его предикативную основу.

2) Наречие ***обычно*** — это **типичный детерминант**, который не образует словосочетания ни с подлежащим, ни со сказуемым, он всегда характеризует только ситуацию, заданную в предложении.

3) **Детерминант может находиться в середине предложения,** например: Обычно //он встает рано. Он обычно //встает рано. **Это разные варианты актуального членения предложения.** Можно сделать детерминант отдельной темой, а можно составить тему из детерминанта и подлежащего.

4) **Такое же актуальное членение** мы видим в предложениях, где ставится тире. Мы делим сообщение на две части, а детерминант относим к одной из них.

5) **В чем разница?**

(1) *Обычно желАние — это лишь чАсть решения о покупке.* Темой является **желание в его обычном проявлении**, то есть детерминант ***обычно*** входит в тему.

(2) *ЖелАние — это обычно лишь чАсть решения о покупке.* Темой является **только желание,** а детерминант ***обычно*** входит в сообщение (рему).

В первом случае тема обозначена **конкретнее, яснее**, и это может быть преимуществом такой конструкции.

Comment: У вас получается противоречие. Вы говорите, что *наречие "обычно" — это типичный детерминант, который не образует словосочетания ни с подлежащим, ни со сказуемым, он всегда характеризует только ситуацию, заданную в предложении*. Затем вы утверждаете, что в предложении "Обычно желание — это лишь часть решения о покупке" *темой является желание в его обычном проявлении, которое определяется во второй части предложения*, т. е. "обычно" относится к подлежащему, характеризует его.

Comment: Актуальное членение - это смысловое, а не грамматическое членение.  В этом случае мы делим предложение на две части, и в каждую часть могут входить слова, не связанные друг с другом грамматически. "Обычно желание - это лишь часть решения о покупке". Здесь в первой части объединены детерминант и подлежащее, которые составляют тему. Я бы только поправила так:Темой является только желание, а детерминант входит в СООБЩЕНИЕ (РЕМУ).

Comment: Конфигурация у нас что? Я этим термином не пользуюсь.

Comment: Вы поправили пояснение к предложению 1 или 2?